# Fluent NHibernate Polymorphic Mapping Challenges

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, mapping, polymorphism

I am having some problems mapping the following scenario in Fluent Nhibernate using Table Per Concrete class:

Let's say I have the following class definitions:

```
public class Reading { .... }

public class CarReading : Reading { .... }

public class TruckReading : Reading { .... }

public class Alert 
{
    ....
    public virtual Reading AReading { get; set; }
}
```

So my question is how to create the mapping class for Alert, if it has a one to one relationship with reading class (could be either truck reading or car reading) and instruct nhibernate to know which table to load the data from (TruckReading table or CarReading Table)

```
public class AlertMap : ClassMap<Alert>
{
    ....
    HasOne(x => x.AReading);
}
```

If anyone could point me in the right direction that would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class AlertMap : ClassMap<Alert>
{
    ....
    ReferenceAny(x => x.AReading)
        .EntityIdentifierColumn("readingid")
        .EntityTypeColumn("readingtype")
        .IdentityType<int>()
        .AddMetaValue<CarReading>("car")
        .AddMetaValue<TruckReading>("truck");
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the values that you put inside AddMetaValue, are those the values that I store in ReadingType column in database?

Comment: yes, thats also the values which NH uses to determine the type of the reference when creating proxies and which table is queried